React Native Expo app no longer displays Firebase Storage images after updating SDK version
I have a React Native app built using Expo, and it was working perfectly before I took a break in April. After coming back, I was required to update some packages to get the app running again on Expo Go. Unfortunately, I can't recall all the packages that were updated, but I believe the main change was upgrading the Expo SDK version.
Since this update, all images in my app that are loaded from Firebase Storage are no longer displaying. These images worked perfectly before the update, and nothing else in my code regarding Firebase or image handling has changed.
Is there a reason why an Expo SDK or related package update would have affected the ability to load Firebase Storage images?
I have since got the images loading but in a completely different way - they don't load as fast this way. I have attached both my new and old code below. I am using a custom CachedImage component for caching, which I had to update for my new approach.
Original code:
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import { firebase } from '../../firebase/config';
import CachedImage from '../../caching/CachedImage';

const Home = () => {
    const [topElement, setTopElement] = useState(null);
    const [topElementScore, setTopElementScore] = useState(null);
    const [playerPhotoRef, setPlayerPhotoRef] = useState(null);
    const [dreamTeamPlayerIds, setDreamTeamPlayerIds] = useState(null);
    const [dreamTeamPlayerPoints, setDreamTeamPlayerPoints] = useState(null);
    const [playerData, setPlayerData] = useState([]);
    const [isPlayerDataFetched, setIsPlayerDataFetched] = useState(false);

    const PlayersApi = Constants.expoConfig.extra.development.BOOTSTRAP_API;
    const EventApi = Constants.expoConfig.extra.development.EVENT_API;

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchData();
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (topElement !== null && isPlayerDataFetched) {
            const playerTeam = getTeamById(topElement);
            const playerPhotoRef = getPlayerPhotoRefById(topElement, playerTeam);
            setPlayerPhotoRef(playerPhotoRef);
        }
    }, [topElement, isPlayerDataFetched]);

    const fetchData = async () => {
        try {
            const response = await axios.get(PlayersApi);
            setPlayerData(response.data.elements);
            const thisEvent = response.data.events.find(event => event.is_current);
            if (thisEvent) {
                const eventApiUrl = EventApi.replace(":eventId", thisEvent.id);
                const eventResponse = await axios.get(eventApiUrl);
                const dreamTeamPlayers = eventResponse.data.elements.filter(player => player.stats.in_dreamteam);
                setDreamTeamPlayerIds(dreamTeamPlayers.map(player => player.id));
                setDreamTeamPlayerPoints(dreamTeamPlayers.map(playerPoints => playerPoints.stats.total_points));
                setTopElement(thisEvent.top_element_info.id);
                setTopElementScore(thisEvent.top_element_info.points);
                setIsPlayerDataFetched(true);
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
        }
    };

    const getPlayerNameById = (playerId) => {
        const player = playerData.find(player => player.id === playerId);
        return player ? `${player.first_name} ${player.second_name}` : 'Unknown Player';
    };

    const getTeamById = (playerId) => {
        const player = playerData.find(player => player.id === playerId);
        return player ? `${player.team}` : 'Unknown Player';
    };

    const getPlayerPhotoRefById = (playerId, playerTeam) => {
        return firebase
            .storage()
            .ref()
            .child(`player-photos/${playerTeam}/${playerId}.png`);
    };

    const sortDreamTeamPlayers = () => {
        const playersWithPositionsAndPoints = dreamTeamPlayerIds.map((playerId, index) => ({
            id: playerId,
            points: dreamTeamPlayerPoints[index]
        }));
        return playersWithPositionsAndPoints;
    };

    return (
        <ScrollView>
            <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
                <View style={styles.headerContainer}>
                    <Text style={styles.headerText}>Top Scorer of the Week</Text>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.playerInfoContainer}>
                    <View style={styles.playerImageContainer}>
                        {isPlayerDataFetched && playerPhotoRef && (
                            <CachedImage
                                key={playerPhotoRef}
                                storageRef={playerPhotoRef}
                                style={styles.playerImage}
                                defaultSource={require('../../assets/icons/0.png')}
                            />
                        )}
                    </View>
                    <View style={styles.playerTextContainer}>
                        <Text style={styles.playerName}>{getPlayerNameById(topElement)}</Text>
                        <Text style={styles.playerScore}>Points: {topElementScore}</Text>
                    </View>
                </View>

                <View style={styles.headerContainer}>
                    <Text style={styles.headerText}>Team of the Week</Text>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.playerTextContainer}>
                    {sortDreamTeamPlayers().map(player => (
                        <View key={player.id} style={styles.playerRow}>
                            <View style={styles.playerPhotoRow}>
                                <CachedImage
                                    storageRef={getPlayerPhotoRefById(player.id, getTeamById(player.id))}
                                    style={styles.playerPhoto}
                                    defaultSource={require('../../assets/icons/0.png')}
                                />
                                <Text style={styles.dreamTeamText}>{getPlayerNameById(player.id)}</Text>
                            </View>
                            <Text style={styles.dreamTeamText}>{player.points}</Text>
                        </View>
                    ))}
                </View>
            </SafeAreaView>
        </ScrollView>
    );
};

export default Home;


New code:
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import { firebase } from '../../firebase/config';
import CachedImage from '../../caching/CachedImage';

const Home = () => {
    const [playerPhotoRef, setPlayerPhotoRef] = useState(null);
    const [dreamTeamImages, setDreamTeamImages] = useState({});
    const [topElement, setTopElement] = useState(null);
    const [dreamTeamPlayerIds, setDreamTeamPlayerIds] = useState([]);
    const [dreamTeamPlayerPoints, setDreamTeamPlayerPoints] = useState(null);
    const [isPlayerDataFetched, setIsPlayerDataFetched] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (topElement !== null && isPlayerDataFetched) {
            const fetchPlayerPhoto = async () => {
                try {
                    const playerTeam = getTeamById(topElement);
                    const photoUrl = await getPlayerPhotoRefById(topElement, playerTeam);
                    setPlayerPhotoRef(photoUrl);
                } catch (error) {
                    console.error("Error fetching player photo in useEffect:", error);
                }
            };
            fetchPlayerPhoto();
        }
    }, [topElement, isPlayerDataFetched]);

    const fetchDreamTeamImages = async () => {
        try {
            const imageFetchPromises = dreamTeamPlayerIds.map(async (playerId) => {
                const playerTeam = getTeamById(playerId);
                return {
                    playerId,
                    photoUrl: await getPlayerPhotoRefById(playerId, playerTeam),
                };
            });

            const resolvedImages = await Promise.all(imageFetchPromises);
            const images = resolvedImages.reduce((acc, { playerId, photoUrl }) => {
                acc[playerId] = photoUrl;
                return acc;
            }, {});

            setDreamTeamImages(images);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("An error occurred", error);
        }
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchDreamTeamImages();
    }, [dreamTeamPlayerIds]);

    const getPlayerPhotoRefById = async (playerId, playerTeam) => {
        try {
            const url = await firebase
                .storage()
                .ref()
                .child(`player-photos/${playerTeam}/${playerId}.png`)
                .getDownloadURL();
            return url;
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("Error fetching photo URL:", error);
            return null;
        }
    };

    return (
        <ScrollView>
            <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
                <View style={styles.playerImageContainer}>
                    {dreamTeamImages[topElement] && (
                        <CachedImage
                            storageRef={dreamTeamImages[topElement]}
                            style={styles.playerImage}
                            defaultSource={require('../../assets/icons/0.png')}
                        />
                    )}
                </View>
                <View style={styles.playerTextContainer}>
                    {dreamTeamPlayerIds.map((playerId) => (
                        <View key={playerId} style={styles.playerRow}>
                            {dreamTeamImages[playerId] && (
                                <CachedImage
                                    storageRef={dreamTeamImages[playerId]}
                                    style={styles.playerPhoto}
                                    defaultSource={require('../../assets/icons/0.png')}
                                />
                            )}
                            <Text style={styles.dreamTeamText}>{getPlayerNameById(playerId)}</Text>
                        </View>
                    ))}
                </View>
            </SafeAreaView>
        </ScrollView>
    );
};

export default Home;

Ideally I would figure out how to get my original code working again.
Thank you!

Try using this package instead that has full support for firebase images and expo: https://github.com/xerdnu/react-native-blasted-image
